# Google Charts Data security

Tags: security, google-visualization

We are considering using Google charts for our project but we have highly confidential data.  Can you use Google Charts without sending the data to Google?

Also, can we run this as a server charting tool also?

Answer (score 5):

You may want to read Google Chart's section on security: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/security_privacy

Specifically:

> Google also does not keep the private data stored in a chart: charts where data is uploaded to Google servers is only done so for the purpose of rendering the charts for you. chart data uploaded to Google servers is maintained a short while for debugging purposes, and then discarded.

And

> All Google-authored charts are developed with privacy and security considerations in mind. All Google chart documentation pages include a data policy section that describes whether a chart sends any chart data from the page.

**EDIT:** Like the quote above says, the data policy for each chart is contained in the documentation for that individual chart. For example: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#Data_Policy

Comment: Thanks.  Based on this line "Some charts perform all their data manipulation on the browser", how do I know which charts upload data and which do not?

Comment: @user1747624 See my edit. If my answer helped you, be sure to mark it as the answer and/or upvote!